# Do homeomorphisms on a circle always send very short arcs to short arcs?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $S^1$ be a circle of perimeter equal to $1$ (not radius $1$) .Let $f: S^1 \to S^1$ be an arbitrary homeomorphism. By uniform continuity, it always possible to find an $\epsilon >0$ such that $d(x,y)<\epsilon$ implies

$$d(f(x),f(y))<\epsilon,$$
where $d$ denote the shortest distance between two points on the circle.

My question is: Is it always possible to find an $\epsilon >0$ such that for any arc $I$ (or call it interval if you like) on $S^1$ such that
$length(I)<\epsilon$ implies that

$$length(f(I))<\frac{1}{4}?$$

In other words, do homeomorphisms always send very short arcs to short arcs, rather than long arcs?

Since a homeomorphism can be expanding or contracting, I am really puzzled by this. There must be some tricks I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

In general, the property you claim holds for compact spaces and is a vital part of the **no small subgroup argument**.

For each point $p \in S^1$, let $q = f(p)$, and let $J_q$ be the arc of length $0.25$ around $q$. Then $f^{-1}(J_q)$ is open, so contains an open interval $I_p$ around $p$. Let $\phi(p) > 0$ be the largest radius of such interval $I_p$. Then we note that
$$\lvert{\phi(p) - \phi(p')\rvert} \leq d(p,p')$$
so $\phi$ is continuous. As $S^1$ is compact, we conclude that $\phi^{-1}$ is upper bounded. Let $N$ be the upper bound, and take $\epsilon = N^{-1}$.